# the query is breaking. How to skip rows PHP

Tags: php, cycle, rows, break, skip

I have a question probably lame but it made me stuck 
I have the a db query

```
 $query_Recordset10 = "SELECT * FROM products 
  WHERE razdel='mix' AND ID='$ID+1' AND litraj='$litri' ORDER BY ID ASC";
$Recordset10 = mysql_query($query_Recordset10, $victor) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset10 = mysql_fetch_array($Recordset10);
$totalRows_Recordset10 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset10);
```

This is the query for the next product in the line based in the ID of the current product thats on the page.

But if the next product matching the criteria in the query is 2 or more ID's ahead my cycle breaks. So is there a way for skipping this rows and get the next ID matching the criteria.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you post the offending do while loop?

Comment: do you have more than 1 record corresponding to each id

Comment: I've corrected the question I am not using do while sorry my mistake.

Comment: you can't get anything with `'$ID+1'` it should be `$ID+1` with no quotes and it will be wrong anyway

Comment: I've tried with
SELECT * FROM products WHERE razdel='mix' AND ID>'$ID' AND litraj='$litri' ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 1
But now I am getting a blank page because the query want's to show the next ID which is not matching the criteria I want to skip rows in which 'razdel' is not 'mix'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query to this:

```
$query_Recordset10 = "SELECT * FROM products 
    WHERE razdel='mix' AND ID > '$ID' AND litraj='$litri' ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 1";
```

So you still only get 1 row returned (if there's anything to return), but you'll be returning the next row (according to ORDER BY ID ASC) versus (potentially) the row with an incremental ID.

Comment: OK But now I am getting a blank page because the query want's to show the next ID which is not matching the criteria I want to skip rows in which 'razdel' is not 'mix'

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT * FROM products`
`WHERE razdel='mix' AND` **ID > $ID** `AND litraj='$litri' ORDER BY ID ASC";`

Answer (score 1):

PROBLEM SOLVED. I still have a lot to learn.

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE razdel='mix' AND ID>'$ID' AND litraj='$litri' ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 1
```

this is the wright line but my mistake was how $ID is generated.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach to loop over an array rather than trying to access by indexes (if you're fetching every value):

```
foreach ($records as $record) {
}
```

instead of

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($records); $i++) {
}
```

or

```
$i = 0;
while ($i < count($records)) {

    $i++;
}
```

or

```
$i = 0;
do {

} while (++$i < count($records));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this query instead:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE razdel='mix' AND ID>$ID AND litraj='$litri' ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 1
```

This will give you the next element after the one with ID of $ID.

Comment: I think this should do thank you. If I am having a problem I will write again.

Comment: OK But now I am getting a blank page because the query want's to show the next ID which is not matching the criteria I want to skip rows in which 'razdel' is not 'mix'